# Compare post levels and user levels wishlist member

Tags: functions, membership, plugin-members

I'm using Wishlist Member plugin and I'm building a function which compares user_levels and post_levels, but I can't get my function to work:

```
check_user_access($userid, $postid){

     // get user_levels
     $user_levels = WLMAPI::GetUserLevels($userid);

     // get the post levels
     $post_levels = WLMAPI::GetPostLevels($postid);

     // Compare user_levels with post_level
     $result = array_search($user_levels, $post_levels);

     if ($result === false) {
         return false;
     }
     else {
         return true;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because $user_levels is an array?

Try something like:

```
// Compare user_levels with post_level
$result = '';
foreach($user_levels as $user_level) {
    $result .= array_search($user_level, $post_levels);
}
if ($result) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for. This will let you find if a user can access a post, page, or category. This uses the new API functions in the latest versions of WishList Member and accepts 'post', 'page', or 'category' as the $object_type parameter.

```
function member_can_access($user_id, $object_type, $object_id) {
    $levels = wlmapi_get_member_levels($user_id);

    $map = array(
        'post' => 'wlmapi_get_level_posts',
        'page' => 'wlmapi_get_level_pages',
        'category' => 'wlmapi_get_level_categories'
    );

    $plurals = array(
        'post' => 'posts',
        'page' => 'pages',
        'category' => 'categories'
    );

    foreach ( $levels as $level ) {
        $objects[] = call_user_func($map[$object_type], $level->Level_ID);
    }

    foreach ( $objects as $object ) {
        foreach ( $object[$plurals[$object_type]][$object_type] as $item ) {
            $items[] = $item['ID'];
        }
    }

    $items = array_unique($items);

    if ( !in_array( $object_id, $items ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

?><pre><?php print_r(member_can_access(1, 'post', 1)); ?></pre>
```

You can see the documentation for all the used functions at http://codex.wishlistproducts.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the old Wishlist Member API, try using the new one it's much more comprehensive. You can find the new API at: http://wishlistproducts.com/api/api2/

The returned variable are object to find out their content use `var_dump` for debugging then just get the required information.